# How to use selector attribute with pseudo elements?

Tags: css

I have a number of CSS categories1-n and I have the following code to assign attributes to all of them:
`[class*="parentcategory"] { float: left; }`

Now some of them also have pseudo elements of ::before and ::after, .e.g `.parentcategory1::before` and I struggle to assign attributes generally to all of these because I have the category number between "parentcategory" and e.g. "::before"

Is there a way to solve this?

Many thanks

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work just fine like so. Any issues with this?

```css
[class*="parentcategory"] {
  color: red;
}

[class*="parentcategory"]::before {
  color: black;
  content: '::before';
}
```

```html
<div class="parentcategory1">
  parentcategory1
</div>

<div class="parentcategory2">
  parentcategory2
</div>
```

Comment: E P I C - that did the trick indeed! Thank you so much, that's really helpful!